# Is there a .net client for administering ejabberd server?

Tags: .net, ejabberd, ejabberd-api

I am looking to be able to control the ejabberd server using a simple .net wrapper over the ejabberd xml-rpc API. Apparently there is already a Java library for this purpose, in addition to Perl (see this: https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/ejabberd-api/admin-api/). I was wondering if one's available for .net? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

the list of libraries are for NET framework such as agsXMPP SDK,Coversant SoapBox SDK Studio,jabber.net,MatriX,Sharp.Xmpp and Ubeity.Select according to your requirement-https://xmpp.org/software/libraries.html   and clients https://xmpp.org/software/clients.html